# Order of intercept-url patterns in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

In appSecurity.xml I have this:

intercept-url pattern="/users/profile/**" access="hasRole('VIEW_PROFILES')".

intercept-url pattern="/users/profile/edit/**" access="hasRole('EDIT_PROFILES')"

I have a page /users/profiles/edit/addnew and when user with role VIEW_PROFILES is trying to access this page, he gets it successfully but the access to user with role EDIT_PROFILES is blocked.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

Since `"/users/profile/edit/"` is more specific than `"/users/profile/"`, it should be placed higher in the list.

**Why**

> Patterns are always evaluated in the order they are defined. Thus it is important that more specific patterns are defined higher in the list than less specific patterns. This is reflected in our example above, where the more specific /secure/super/ pattern appears higher than the less specific /secure/ pattern. If they were reversed, the /secure/ pattern would always match and the /secure/super/ pattern would never be evaluated.

**Source: [Core Security Filters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/core-web-filters.html#filter-security-interceptor)**

Comment: In my case `<intercept-url pattern="/api/v1/company" method="GET" access="permitAll()" />` is more specific than `<intercept-url pattern="/api/v1/company/**" access="hasRole('...')" />` for me this was not obvious at first.

Comment: @Matthew, the specificity rules in this case are same as those for request mapping. See [Path Pattern Comparison](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html): _A pattern with a lower count of URI variables and wild cards is considered more specific. For example /hotels/{hotel}/* has 1 URI variable and 1 wild card and is considered more specific than /hotels/{hotel}/** which as 1 URI variable and 2 wild cards._ ....

Answer (score 2):

Both John Farrelly and Ritesh are correct. The `intercept-url` patterns are matched in the order listed. As soon as a match is found, the rest of the patterns specified are ignored. This is why you should list more specific patterns earlier.

In your case, the pattern for */users/profile/edit/somepage* matches the pattern specified in the first `intercept-url` pattern, so Spring is appropriately checking to see if the user in question has the access role specified. Apparently, your EDIT_PROFILES users do not have VIEW_PROFILES authority, so they are being denied access. Likewise, your intention to restrict access to *../edit/* to users with EDIT_PROFILES authority is being undermined by the earlier statement which grants access to users with VIEW_PROFILES authority.

Switch the order for the easy fix, and you probably want to give your EDIT_PROFILES users VIEW_PROFILES authority (in addition to EDIT_PROFILES authority). Then, consider using `access="hasAnyRole('REQUIRED_ROLE')"` rather than `access="hasRole('REQUIRED_ROLE')"`, to simplify the access statements.

Comment: complete and easy to understand, theorical and practically useful, good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your EDIT_PROFILES rule is above the VIEW_PROFILES rule.  If you take a look at the expression for VIEW_PROFILES, you will see that it includes every URL that would match EDIT_PROFILES.  That means that if the VIEW_PROFILES rule is first, spring security will never bother to try the EDIT_PROFILES rule.