# I am using spring form Security with "Bootstrap/Bootsfaces". styling not working initially ? After i login styling works

Tags: jsf, spring-security

**Some How i am blocking resources(External Folders and Jars Folder) ? I don't know how to configure this in XML.**

[Project Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWUbY.jpg)

```
    <!-- Page level Spring Security : Intercept access to resources in /pages/secure/** -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/pages/secure/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR')" />

    <!-- Page level Spring Security : Permit access to resources in /pages/unsecure/** -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/pages/unsecure/**" access="permitAll"/>

    <!-- Page level Spring Security : Intercept access to resources in /** -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR')"/>

    <!-- Page level Spring Security : Enable Primefaces -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll"/>

    <!-- Define login page for Spring Security -->
    <sec:form-login login-page="/pages/unsecure/login_bootstrap.xhtml"/>

    <!-- Define logout properties for Spring Security -->
    <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="true" logout-success-url="/"></sec:logout>
</sec:http>
```

Comment: Same cause as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373178/primefaces-based-application-with-picketlink-does-not-show-style-in-login-page

Comment: I have already exclude faces.resources from security. Still facing issue .

Comment: order of rules? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998746/order-of-intercept-url-patterns-in-spring-security