# how to setup different access for nested url's in spring-security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

here is my security config:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("**/feedback")
                .access("hasAnyAuthority('MANAGER','EMPLOYEE')")
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**","/ticket/**")
                .access("isAuthenticated()")
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("**/create/**")
                .access("hasAnyAuthority('MANAGER','EMPLOYEE')")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                .and().formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/ticket/all", true)
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

i want everyone to have access for viewing tickets "/ticket" , but i want to forbid access for an engineer to /ticket/create and /ticket/**/feedback. Right now

```
antMatchers("/api/**","/ticket/**")
                    .access("isAuthenticated()")
```

Allows to access everyone. How should i do it properly? Is there some kind of overwriting rule for multiple antMatchers?

Comment: First matching rule wins so place the more specific restrictions before the more general rule in the configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998746/order-of-intercept-url-patterns-in-spring-security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want everyone to have access for viewing tickets "/ticket"

Everyone means *Authenticated user*? or *Authenticated+Anonymous* user ?

- For Authenticated user `.antMatchers("/ticket").access("isAuthenticated()")`
- For Authenticated+Anonymous `.antMatchers("/ticket").permitAll()`

> but i want to forbid access for an **engineer** to `/ticket/create` and `/ticket/**/feedback`.
>   ***Engineer?** Your question has incomplete information.

Assuming roles `MANAGER` `EMPLOYEE` and `ENGINEER` and all are authenticated users then

Modify for allowing ticket creation only for `MANAGER` and `EMPLOYEE`

```java
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("**/feedback")
            .access("hasAnyAuthority('MANAGER','EMPLOYEE')")
    .and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/**","/ticket/**")
            .access("isAuthenticated()")
    .and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("**/create/**")
            .access("hasAnyAuthority('MANAGER','EMPLOYEE')")
```

to

```java
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/ticket").access("isAuthenticated()") //or .permitAll() as explained already
        .antMatchers("**/feedback", "/ticket/**", "**/create/**")
            .access("hasAnyAuthority('MANAGER','EMPLOYEE')")
        .antMatchers("/api/**")
            .access("isAuthenticated()");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add following code:

```
.and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/ticket").permitAll()
```

The code will be:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("**/feedback")
                .access("hasAnyAuthority('MANAGER','EMPLOYEE')")
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/ticket")
                .permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**","/ticket/**")
                .access("isAuthenticated()")
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("**/create/**")
                .access("hasAnyAuthority('MANAGER','EMPLOYEE')")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                .and().formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/ticket/all", true)
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().csrf().disable();
```

I hope help you.